# Binance API - Account has insufficient balance for requested action

Tags: php, binance

While trying to place an order, I'm receiving the following error:

> Code: -2010 Account has insufficient balance for requested action

I'm requesting the POST endpoint https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order with the following parameters:

```
$params = 
[
    'symbol' => 'BTCUSDT',
    'side' => 'BUY',
    'type' => 'MARKET',
    'quoteOrderQty' => 375.00,
    'timestamp' => $timestamp,
];
```

And I just deposit 400$, which means I have enough funds to purchase 375$ worth of BTC.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think this is no problem with your code. Everything here looks very good.
Try to get your current amount of USDT on your spot account. I have two versions. You have USD instead of USDT on your spot wallet, or you have 400 USDT on the p2p wallet insead of spot.

Comment: Hi Mike. I deposited 400€, which translated to 450$~. Now I expect to trade in USD, since I always look at the prices of the coins in $ and not €. Are you telling me that I should trade in EUR and buy `BTCEUR` instead?

Comment: Nope. I just suggest you find our money and convert it to USDT if you want. Check this page using your browser https://www.binance.com/en/my/wallet/account/main and find what currency do you have now. Keep in mind that USD != USDT

Comment: Thanks Mike, it worked, I used this https://www.binance.com/en/convert link, would you like to set as an answer to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you find your money and convert it to USDT if you want. Check this page using your browser https://binance.com/en/my/wallet/account/main and find what currency do you have now. Keep in mind that USD != USDT

Answer (score 1):

I have had this before numerous times and this is why it happens.

Say you have 0.007821 worth of BTC in your Binance Wallet. And you are trying to place a SELL order.  Now, if you end up rounding your quantity to say 4 decimal places, your code would try and SELL 0.0079 BTC. This is obviously more than what you have in your Exchange Wallet. This will cause the "Account has insufficient balance for requested action" error.

Solution:  Simply match or reduce the amount in your code that you are trying to SELL to match the amount in your exchange Wallet. So, in this case, try and use the correct rounding decimal places or try to SELL 0.0078 worth of BTC.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to make sure you have enough BNB in your account to pay for the fees:
https://dev.binance.vision/t/account-has-insufficient-balance-for-requested-action/2718/6

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to buy 375.00 bitcoin.

`quoteOrderQty` must reference to the amount of `symbol` you want to buy.

if you want to buy btc for a percentage of your total money you should use this formula: `(YourTotalMoney / CurrentPrice) * (Percentage / 100)`

Example: I want to buy BTC using 50% of my USDT

`Quantity = (getBalanceUSDT() / getCurrentPriceBTC()) * (50 / 100)`

`getBalanceUSDT()` and `getCurrentPriceBTC()` are functions you will have to create

Now you can use `Quantity` for the `quoteOrderQty` param.

Comment: This is the correct answer because the base currency is BTC