# Api says insufficient balance while I have more than enough

Tags: python, api, binance

I am trying to create a connection with the binance-api. But when I try to buy a certain coin, in this case PANCAKESWAP, I get the following error:

binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2010): Account has insufficient balance for requested action.

I know that I have more than enough free balance and I am able to buy other coins. I have no idea what i need to change here, placing a limit order gives me the same error and filling in the order manually on their website works fine with the exact same values. This has bothered me for a few hours now and several threads haven't gotten me any wiser. Here is my code:

```
url = "https://api.binance.com/api"

api_secret = "X"
api_key = "X"

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
client.API_URL = url

# get latest price from Binance API
coin_price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=stringShot)
price = coin_price['price']

#get precision
info = client.get_symbol_info(stringShot)
print(info['filters'][2]['minQty'])
test = info['filters'][2]['minQty']
deci = test.index('1')  # precision is noted as 0.00001, so the index of 1 is the precision.
print(deci)

#get amount of usdt
balance = client.get_asset_balance(asset='USDT')
print(balance['free'])

usdt = (float(11)/float(price))  # buy 11 dollars worth of coin
quantity = float(round(usdt,(deci - 1))) # get the right precision by rounding the numbers 
print(usdt)
print(quantity)

#Convert it in order to buy for a certain amount of USDT
if float(balance['free'])>float(11):  # if there is more than 11 usdt available, buy
        pass

else:
        print("Not enough USDT available.")
        

order = client.create_order(
        symbol=stringShot,
        side=Client.SIDE_BUY,
        type=Client.ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
        quantity=quantity
)  #market order for buying the coin
```

Comment: I also got same problem, if your problem has solved, please tell me that to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same probleme, but i looked at this website : [Binance API - Account has insufficient balance for requested action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178953/binance-api-account-has-insufficient-balance-for-requested-action)
it's about coding in php i know but it's easily convertible to python.
Just some hints :

- check you have some money in BNB to pay for the fees.
- check your portfolio is a spot one, not a p2p, or else
- check you use USDT instead of USD